# unknown parsing error in soql query

Tags: soql

I receive unknown parsing error while executing following soql query in dev console.

```
SELECT Name,OwnerId from account where ID in (Select AccountId from User WHERE Id = 00536000005bkdTAAQ)
```

I want to look at accounts associated with this user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap the `Id` value in single quotes (`'`):

```
WHERE Id = '00536000005bkdTAAQ'
//         ^   missing these  ^
```

Comment: Oh thank you. . I have tried above correction and result comes back as 0. While that user is owner of atleast 2 accounts that I know of

Comment: If you want to filter on this user owning the records you would do `WHERE OwnerId = '005...'`.

Comment: SELECT Name,OwnerId from contact where OwnerId ='00536000005bkdTAAQ';  I tried that and I am getting parsing error agian'

Comment: Why did you change the query object from `Account` to `Contact`?

Comment: Actually I am troubleshooting on both objects. chaged back to account but error is still same.

Comment: Are you including a semicolon in the query itself? That is not valid syntax. Please update your question post with the exact query you are still struggling with.

Comment: Oh man yes I was.. Thak you. That returned with rows.